# 2006 VW Jetta Brake Rotor

Tags: brakes, vw, jetta

I have a 2006 VW Jetta 2.5L with 1K in the VIN. there are 2 different size brake rotors for the front and the back. need to order without being able to measure as the car is at college.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to call a VW parts department with your VIN number to be sure, but one of my favorite VW parts sites, GermanAutoParts, shows that your car needs [260mm Rear](http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Jetta/Brake/74/16) rotors and [288mm Front](http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Jetta/Brake/72/21) rotors (I'm not going to guarantee that this will fit your car, but if you email them, they might..).

The problem with the Jetta is that it was available with 3 different engines, and a few different trim packages that year, including the GLI package that is only available in a few year models.

Try looking at parts websites that specialize in VW or German parts rather than the big mega-sites.  Their search functions are tailored more for your vehicle.

Comment: Also, notice [this tool](http://www.germanautoparts.com/productdisplay/94677) on one of the brake rotor searches I linked to.  I think this tool is a requirement on your car to do a brake job (and you wouldn't have it unless you have a decent VW wrenching history).  Check the Bently manual if you can, or look at some VW forums for brake job how-tos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only seeing 288 x 25 on the front, and 260 x 10 on the rear listed for 2006 Jetta 2.5.